# omnet++ installation error in windows 7

Tags: omnet++

I am tring to install omnet++ but it gives me error "windows can not find ",is there anyone can help

I have been trying  mingmenv.cmd gives me the same error

it gives as shown below error when I try to install:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, did you unpack the OMNeT Windows installation file with the on-board ZIP tools or another program? Try to use programs like WinRAR or 7-Zip to unpack the OMNeT++ installation, the on-board ZIP tool from Windows 7 might have problems with the MinGW files.

Second, does the path to the OMNeT++ installation contain any spaces or special characters? This might also be the source of errors.

Third, does the message immediately show after you start the `mingwenv.cmd` or after you start it and try to run `./configure` or `make` to configure and build OMNeT?? Check if no antivirus might block the OMNeT sources / helper programs.

General note: under Windows, you always use the `mingwenv.cmd` shell to compile OMNeT, the normal Windows command environment does not have the necessary paths or settings for OMNMeT.